# fitting a distribution to the following histogram

Tags: probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling

This is a histogram showing the 'distribution' of speeds that were measured while a certain animal was moving. $x$ axis shows the speeds in m/s and $y$ axis shows the frequency, hence the resulting histogram.

[image]

I wanted to ask: Can I fit a distribution to the given histogram and what would be an appropriate choice and why? (Gamma? Gaussian skewed to the right?)

The ultimate purpose would be to make a model based on the given data set.

Insights are welcome.

Comment: This seems rather like statistics. See [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: A horse has several modes of locomotion, walk, trot, canter, gallop, each or which would exhibit a range of speeds. Hence if you monitored a horse over a long period of time you would have several distributions overlaid to produce something quite complex. Given that your histogram looks like it could have several peaks I wonder if something similar is true for your animal.